# What is this chip? Labeled "ATMEL 60824C08"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

This chip came from a box of assorted ICs from ebay. I have looked up the code on the top and I can't work out what this actually is.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [24C08 EEPROM](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8787-SEEPROM-AT24C04C-08C-Datasheet.pdf) memory chip. The `608` is a date code for `2016`, week `08`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [24C08](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AT24C04C-AT24C08C-I2C-Compatible-%20Two-Wire-Serial-EEPROM-4-Kbit-8-Kbit-20006127A.pdf), a very common EEPROM chip with I2C interface. 1024 x 8. Old datasheets should lead you to the speed but it should operate at 100 and 400kHz at least.